# How to find the pair in the set using first element of the pair only?

Tags: c++, set

Hello I have a set of pair which contains the following elements.

```
set < pair<int,int> >st;
st.insert(make_pair(1,2));
st.insert(make_pair(4,5));
st.insert(make_pair(7,8));
```

Now I want to delete the pair from the set based on first element of the pair 
using `set.erase()`.?

```
In - {(1,2),(4,5),{7,8}}
To achieve -  set.erase({1}).
out- {(4,5),(7,8)} // removing member of set using first element of pair.
```

Please help to achieve this. Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Pay special attention to [How To Create MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The more effort you'll put into posting a good question: one which is easy to read, understand and which is [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) - the chances are higher that it will attract the relevant people and you'll get help even faster. Good luck!

Answer (score 5):

If you want to delete an element using `erase` method, you need to get iterator to removed position, use `find_if` algorithm with predicate to find element, and pass this iterator to `erase` method.

```
    auto it = std::find_if(st.begin(), st.end(), [](const pair<int,int>& p ){ return p.first == 1; });
    if (it != st.end())
        st.erase(it);
```

Comment: Thanks for the code @rafix07 .It served my purpose.

Answer (score 4):

`std::map` is perfect fit for your need. There is `erase` by key method on `map`.

But if you really need to use `set`, use standard algorithm to find element and then use `erase` on set using iterator returned by `find_if` algorithm.

Comment: I want the elements to be sorted based on the second element of the pair therefore I am using set and not map. However how could i find the element  in log(n) using first element of pair by using standard algorithm as suggested by you .Please expand @Elvis Oric

Comment: Use standard algorithm to find element and then call erase on set using returned  iterator.

Comment: Normally using standard algorithms costs O(n) time. To achieve O(log n) time, you can maintain two `map`s, one works as normal (using the second elements as keys), and the other stores pairs of values of the previous `map` and iterators pointing to corresponding elements in the previous `map`. Just remember to update the second `map` when inserting or erasing elements.

Comment: Good point @xskxzr, some kind of cross maps. Wrap your operations in new class so you can be sure that you updated states of maps on inserting and erasing elements.